# carasoul slider for gallery post not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have create a custom post for showing gallery  on home page and fetch all the post on home page need to show the 6 images in each slider

please check below code..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row second-row">
        <div   
            class="container">
            <h2>gallery</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy  
                text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </p>
            <nav>
                <ul   
                    class="control-box pager">
                    <li><a data-slide="prev"   
                        href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon   
                        glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a data-slide="next"   
                        href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon   
                        glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div   
            class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="carousel slide   
                    text-center" id="myCarousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <?php   
                            $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'gallery',   
                            'posts_per_page' => 6 )); while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :   
                            $the_query->the_post(); ?> 
                        <div class="item active">
                            <ul   
                                class="thumbnails">
                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <div class="fff">
                                        <div   
                                            class="thumbnail"> <a href="#"><img alt="" src="<img src="<?php   
                                            the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>"></a> </div>
                                        <p><?php   
                                            the_title();?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Slide1 --> <?php  
                            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?> <?php $the_query = new   
                            WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'gallery', 'posts_per_page' => 6,   
                            'offset' => 1 )); while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :   
                            $the_query->the_post(); ?> 
                        <div class="item">
                            <ul class="thumbnails">
                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <div class="fff">
                                        <div class="thumbnail"> <a   
                                            href="#"> <img src="<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>   
                                            "></a> </div>
                                        <p><?php the_title();?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /Slide2 --> <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

---